# vbScript - Using Select/Case with an array

Tags: vbscript

I need help with the following:

```
Dim reportesTA(2)
reportesTA(0) = "Report1"
reportesTA(1) = "Report2"
```

I want to execute certain actions for each item in the array list. So I was thinking of working with a Select/Case. I tried this but didn't work:

```
Select Case reportesTA
Case 0
//do stuff
Case 1
//do stuff
End Select
```

Is there any way to get the cases switch? something like a switch/case? Anyone has a better way to work with each item of the array? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim reportesTA(2)
reportesTA(0) = "Report1"
reportesTA(1) = "Report2"

For I = LBound(reportesTA) to UBound(reportesTA)
    Select Case reportesTA(I)
        Case "Report1"
            MsgBox "Report1"
        Case "Report2"
            MsgBox "Report2"
    End Select
Next
```

Explanation:

In "FOR" cycle we passing through of all elements in array, starting from first one till last one.

function "LBound" return lowest ID of available element in array.

function "UBound" return highest ID of available element in array.

In "SELECT CASE" we taking value (yes, it has string type) of element from array and then making decision what we should do -- in this sample we popup message box that displaying report name.

Comment: Would you be able to add a little explanation for the OP and future visitors?

Answer (score 0):

You need to de the Select case with an element of the array, not the array itself.

I would do it  like this, more clear as to what you are doing and more DRY.

```
reportesTA = Array("Report1", "Report2")

Sub do_stuff(text)
  WScript.echo text
End Sub

For each element in reportesTA
  Select Case element
    Case "Report1"
      do_stuff "Report1"
    Case "Report2"
      do_stuff "Report2"
  End Select
Next
```

In this example you would rather do the following

```
For each element in reportesTA
  do_stuff element
Next
```